# UITableView reloads on show view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Please help me to understand why table view reloads on view controller start. I setup outlet for table via storyboard and data source, delegate. I did't call tableView reloadData method. 
So When view controller starts '..numberOfRowsInSection' and other table view delegates methods called.

Comment: when the method called awakeFromNib(), you can override this method to preset anything

Comment: how are displaying the viewcontroller's view? are you presenting the same reference? or are you creating a new viewcontroller object everytime you show it?

Answer (score 0):

as Apple docs say:

> UITableView overrides the layoutSubviews method of UIView so that it
>   calls reloadData only when you create a new instance of UITableView or
>   when you assign a new data source. Reloading the table view clears
>   current state, including the current selection. However, if you
>   explicitly call reloadData, it clears this state and any subsequent
>   direct or indirect call to layoutSubviews does not trigger a reload.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/

If you really do not need its reloading, create your tableView as a lazy variable and add it to a view programmaticaly when you need it.